# Optimizing huge value list in Teradata without volatile tables

Tags: sql, teradata, volatile, cognos, query-tuning

Have a value list like`

```
`where a.c1 in ( list ) `
```

Then shoving the list in the volatile table is the best way out. However this is being done via cognos & IBM isn't smart enough to know what Teradata's volatile table is. 
I wish It was so I could use exclusion logic Exists to  go through the volatile table contents. 
So without volatile table , I have a value list 
 `where a.c1 in ( list )`
which has like 5K values. Keeping that list in the report is proving expensive. I wondered if it was possible to store this kind of list some place  before bringing it in the   report. How about CTE and using exists on a CTE , would that achieve similar gains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the list as a string and then split it into a table, e.g. for a list of integers:

```
where a.c1 in
 (
   SELECT CAST(token AS INT)
   FROM TABLE (STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(1, '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,5000', ',')
        RETURNS (outkey INTEGER,
                 tokennum INTEGER,
                 token VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET UNICODE)
              ) AS dt 
 )
```

Of course the optimizer has no knowledge about the number of rows returned, so better check Explain...

Comment: Thanks so much. I will give that a try and post a follow up in terms of before & after metrics

Comment: My list is a string list each string is 10 char. What I'd have done is just the spool table for an exclusion join `where EXISTS ( sel '1' from table where vt.x=fct.y ) `.  I am not sure if this  table created on the fly can be used inside it . I guess I'd have to inner join if after nominating dt as an extra table in the main query  with conditon `fact.y=dt.token`  ?

Comment: I just tried a `NOT EXISTS`/ EXISTS` and got a strange plans for both, only joins and `IN` look good. You talk about *exclusion join*  which indicates `NOT EXISTS`, you might rewrite it using the `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE token IS NULL` approach

Comment: Just on a follow up - the impact CPU came down from 175K to 5K. thanks a bunch again